# Can you chain backgroundImage and backgroundPosition?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Having trouble figuring out how to use backgroundImage and backgroundPosition with the DOm method. Looking to use the background image and adjust the positioning

```
 window.onload = function() {
var slime =  "url(https://www.dropbox.com/s/scdx0a0ck16abtv/slime.jpg?raw=1)";
   document.getElementsByTagName('main').style.backgroundImage = "url(https://www.dropbox.com/s/scdx0a0ck16abtv/slime.jpg?raw=1)";
slime.style.backgroundPosition = '25% 75%';
};
```

Comment: Use your browsers dev tools inspect facility to see the JS errors. Two immediate problems: you need to get a single main element, not a collection, and it is that element you need to style, not the url string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm breaking this up and adding comments for clarity (what @A Haworth said above is spot on, however).

```
window.onload = function() {
  // define and store image url with proper formatting
  var slime =  "url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/scdx0a0ck16abtv/slime.jpg?raw=1')";

  // get the main element from the DOM (there are multiple ways of accomplishing this)
  let main = document.querySelector('main');

  // set background image of main element
  main.style.backgroundImage = slime;

  // set position of background image
  main.style.backgroundPosition = '25% 75%';
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

The *"chaining"* CSS properties is called [*shorthand*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) which can apply to some CSS properties. Fortunately `backgound` property does, here's the list:

background:

- background-color
- background-image
- background-repeat
- background-attachment
- background-position

It has to be in that order delimitted with a space, and any value can be omitted (but at least one is needed). So OP would be:

```
background: url(https://www.dropbox.com/s/scdx0a0ck16abtv/slime.jpg?raw=1) 25% 75%

/* You should add "no-repeat" betwwen -image and -position if the image dimensions 
are smaller than the element's dimension, unless you want a wallpaper effect */
```

That `property: value` is referred to as a [*CSS ruleset*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax#css_rulesets). In order to actually apply any CSS ruleset to an element inline with the [`.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property, is to use [`.setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) method along with it.

```
node.style.setProperty(property, value);
```

```js
const main = document.querySelector('main');

const property = 'background';

const value = `url(https://www.dropbox.com/s/scdx0a0ck16abtv/slime.jpg?raw=1) 25% 75%`;

main.style.setProperty(property, value);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

main {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```